# What is an appropriate way to give others a resource of mine on Stack Overflow ; a C#/NET glossary?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've spent more time than is healthy creating a spreadsheet that has links to (currently) 725 terms that deal with C#, .NET, general programming, & computing.  I think it did me more harm than good to make it, seeing as how I could have spent that time getting more experienced as a programmer, but my [ADHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_deficit_hyperactivity_disorder) has proved an obstacle.

It originated as a way to keep track of [analog flashcards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashcard) of the same terms (written on Post-Its of every color), and later became a way to keep track of how well I was remembering those terms.  Finally, I made sure to link every term to the source of its information: C# Spec/Programming Guide/Reference, NET Guide, Wikipedia, and other places such as Stack Overflow.

I'm in the process of making online flashcards for it through another website, and I'm about 33% done.  That way others could use it for all intended purposes.
Here's a demo pic:

[image]

It does have other slightly useless resources.  Such as an [ANTLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) guide for the C# Spec.  A list of all the sections in the C# Programming Guide & how many minutes each supposedly takes to read.

Comment: Don't worry. [My list](http://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_2019-11-01.html) is longer! - for a different purpose (and [a web application](http://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=cpu) is taking shape).

Comment: Only curious: How do *you* use it now (e.g. for look up)? Do you intend to remember all 725 terms? Where are the definitions for the terms? Are the definitions self-contained or are they only links?

Comment: Well, every so often (I try to do it at least once it every couple of months), I go through all of my manually written flashcards & see what I can get.  In the score column I put either a 1 or -1 depending on if I get it right or not.  I compare that to past sessions to see if any progress is made.  My best is about 82%. There are some definitions on the spreadsheet, but it's mostly just links.  Once I finish my online flashcards (https://www.cram.com/flashcards/c-sharp-11109040) I'll be able to put away the Post-Its version.  It's also sortable by the link destination.

Comment: Nice list btw, I just took a look.  Much more extensive.  I have a huge list of possible definitions, but I take so long to write down a single flashcard (manually) that I'm selective about what I write down.  In case you're interested, here's an old picture of all of them.  It's grown quite a bit since then.  https://i.imgur.com/efzPIxi.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SO is a Q&A site for practical programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Nothing more, nothing less.

So if you can think of a practical programming question that your glossary, as a whole, answers, you can ask and self-answer it.

Note that an SO answer must be self-sufficient -- i.e. contain all the *critical* pieces of information needed to resolve the problem. Since you can't fit your entire glossary into an answer, it'll probably contain key principles of compiling one, and then link to your external resource as a ready-to-use sample implementation.